# NSXMLParsing for particular tag value

Tags: nsxmlparser

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
 <country>
            <routes>
                <SourceCountry>Ireland</SourceCountry>
                <SourcePort>Larne</SourcePort>
                <DestinationCountry>UK</DestinationCountry>
                <DestinationPort>Troon </DestinationPort>
                        </routes>
            <routes>
                <SourceCountry>Ireland</SourceCountry>
                <SourcePort>Larne</SourcePort>
                <DestinationCountry>UK</DestinationCountry>
                <DestinationPort>Cairnryan </DestinationPort>
                        </routes>
            <routes>
                <SourceCountry>Ireland</SourceCountry>
                <SourcePort>Belfast</SourcePort>
                <DestinationCountry>UK</DestinationCountry>
                <DestinationPort>Birkenhead </DestinationPort>
                        </routes>
            <routes>
                <SourceCountry>Ireland</SourceCountry>
                <SourcePort>Belfast</SourcePort>
                <DestinationCountry>Belgium</DestinationCountry>
                <DestinationPort>Heysham </DestinationPort>
                        </routes>
            <routes>
                <SourceCountry>Belgium</SourceCountry>
                <SourcePort>Warrenpoint</SourcePort>
                <DestinationCountry>UK</DestinationCountry>
                <DestinationPort>Heysham </DestinationPort>
                        </routes>
```

I want parse particular data for `<SourceCountry> == Ireland and <DestinationCountry> == UK`. How can I do this?

Comment: Please stop posting duplicate questions. I've merged both into this as the duplicate had up-voted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **NSXMLParser**

1. implement the delegate for this class ... `<NSXMLParserDelegate>`
2. implement the methods for this parser...

   YOU will need the following methods..

   `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict`

   `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string`

You can read [this tutorial](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html); it is simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

This may help

[Accessing specific child elements when parsing RSS with NSXMLParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216472/accessing-specific-child-elements-when-parsing-rss-with-nsxmlparser)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use XML parser, Use NSXMLParser to parse you data.
Below is the apple sample code of ImageMap in which they have used the NSXMLParser to parse XML content.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009015

Answer (score 1):

Try this . . .

```
int element=0;
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:filepath];
```

following methods are the delegates of NSXMLParser

```
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{   
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:URL];
    parser = [[ NSClassFromString(@"NSXMLParser") alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{   
    NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{           
    if(([elementName compare:@"SourceCountry"])==NSOrderedSame)
        element=1;
    if(([elementName compare:@"SourcePort"])==NSOrderedSame)
        element=2;
    if(([elementName compare:@"DestinationCountry"])==NSOrderedSame)
        element=3;
    if(([elementName compare:@"DestinationPort"])==NSOrderedSame)
        element=4;


}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{   


}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (element==1)
    {
        [TotalXMLArray addObject:string];       
        element=0;
    }
    if (element==2)
    {
        [TotalXMLArray addObject:string];       
        element=0;
    }
    if (element==3)
    {
        [TotalXMLArray addObject:string];       
        element=0;
    }
    if (element==4)
    {
        [TotalXMLArray addObject:string];       
        element=0;
    }

}
```

Comment: how to compare string parse string  for "<SourceCountry> ==Ireland and <DestinationCountry> == UK"

Comment: When i find the string within the tag i was storing in the array named TotalXMLArray and i was accessing the value using array index, instead of it try to store the value in the dictionary, i mean store 4 tags in a dictionary and store that dictionary in array, you'll get array of dictionary having your xml data

Comment: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html, use this link, you don't to break your head to parse xml, xpathquery it self will give you the parse array of dictionary in a single method call.

Comment: thanx pradeep  I am new in iphone. i am want parse only those tag which is content perticular value like "<SourceCountry> Ireland</SourceCountry>  and <DestinationCountry>UK</SourceCountry>"

Comment: Even i started iphone programming few months back, :-) use xpathquery, follow that link you'll find how to integrate xpath, and visit w3schools website for additional info about how to write xpathqueries, in your care query will be "/country/routes/sourceCountry"  and "/country/routes/destinationCountry"