# NSXMLParsing for particular tag value

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSXMLParsing for particular tag value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308853/nsxmlparsing-for-particular-tag-value)

Hi, My xml file like that...

```
     <routes> 
         <SourceCountry> Ireland </SourceCountry> 
         <SourcePort> Larne </SourcePort> 
         <DestinationCountry> UK< /DestinationCountry> 
         <DestinationPort> Troon  </DestinationPort> 
     </routes> 
     <routes> 
         <SourceCountry> Ireland </SourceCountry> 
         <SourcePort> Larne </SourcePort> 
         <DestinationCountry> UK </DestinationCountry> 
         <DestinationPort >Cairnryan  </DestinationPort>
     </routes> 
     <routes> 
         <SourceCountry> France </SourceCountry> 
         <SourcePort> Belfast </SourcePort> 
         <DestinationCountry> UK </DestinationCountry> 
         <DestinationPort> Birkenhead  </DestinationPort> 
     </routes> 
     <routes> 
         <SourceCountry> France </SourceCountry> 
         <SourcePort> Belfast </SourcePort> 
         <DestinationCountry> UK </DestinationCountry> 
         <DestinationPort> Heysham  </DestinationPort> 
     </routes>
```

I want to parse particular data for  `<SourceCountry>`  == **Ireland** and   `<DestinationCountry>` == **UK**
please help me

thank in advance