# Yahoo weather API using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, nsxmlparser, weather-api

This is the documentation provided by Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

At the moment this is my code:

```
NSString *location =  @"Palermo";
NSString *temperatureUnit = @"c";
NSString *address = @"http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=";
NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@&u=%@",address,location, temperatureUnit];
NSURL * URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];
NSXMLParser * doc = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

I'd like to know how to get the temperature value using NSXMLParser

Comment: By implementing the appropriate delegate methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSXMLParser for particular tag value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5308853)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create your parser, but you don't parse. Let's assume you created your parser like so:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

You then need to set the delegate and initiate the parse:

```
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
```

You then have to write your [`NSXMLParserDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods. (For more information on `NSXMLParser`, see the [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i).) E.g., if you only need temperature, you could write a `didStartElement` method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"yweather:condition"])
    {
        // do whatever you want with `attributeDict`, perhaps saving it in some class property; I'm just going to log it

        NSLog(@"current condition = %@", attributeDict); 
    }           
}
```

Note, the city should be a WOEID. (See the [API description](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/).) So, instead of a location of:

```
NSString *location =  @"Palermo";
```

You should use (for Palermo in Italy):

```
NSString *location =  @"719846";
```

---

By the way, I agree with Caleb that you should either do this `initWithContentsOfURL` in a background queue, or you should otherwise retrieve the `NSData` using some asynchronous mechanism.

For example, you could do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSString *location = @"719846";
    NSString *temperatureUnit = @"c";
    NSString *address = @"http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=";
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@&u=%@",address,location, temperatureUnit];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:request];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
});
```

If you do this in the background queue, make sure to dispatch UI updates back to the main queue, e.g.:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"yweather:condition"])
    {
        // UI updates should be dispatched back to the main queue, e.g.:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSString *temp = attributeDict[@"temp"];
            self.tempLabel.text = temp;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I hope this will help other people

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create an URL request from that URL, make the request with`NSURLConnection`, and receive the response. There are a number of good examples in Apple's documentation, so no need to repeat them here. Or, you can use `initWithContentsOfURL:` as you're doing above, but don't do that in the main thread as it'll cause your app to freeze until the response is received; if the server takes too long to respond, iOS will kill your app. Once you have the response, you'll parse it with the XML parser -- you'll need to create a delegate so that the parser can hand you the data as it encounters it during parsing.

Comment: can you give me the link to the example provided by apple

Comment: [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) for one, but this is such a common task that here are many examples.

Comment: thanks for the advice! however if you want, could you explain me more precisely how to parse my data?